# Isn't it misleading that pencil icon is used to indicate an info and not an action

Tags: discussion, uxexchange, ux

Isn't a pencil icon typically used for an edit action, especially when it's used without any accompanying text?

However, ux.stackexchange.com uses pencil icon as an indicator that the comment has been edited (screenshot below). Isn't this counterintuitive for a pencil icon to not be an action?

Is there any particular reason why it is so?

[image: Pencil icon used to indicate past edits rather than an action]

Comment: Do you have an alternative suggestion to a pencil?

Comment: How about a gray text saying "[edited]", immediately after the comment message? This is a common pattern I've seen. Ex: Facebook and Slack.